# permission denied when using `sudo grep syslog` inside perl script (cgi-bin)

Tags: perl, sudo, cgi-bin

i have perl script inside my cgi-bin folder, what i want is grep syslog using sudo grep (because it is root), but i got this message

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

```
#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

so, any solution to solve this problem ??

Comment: This is not an error, this is just the warning that appears when you first use sudo. The error or password prompt would occur afterward.

Comment: What about removing sudo from the script and running the script with sudo or as root? On some systems sudo requires password interactively and would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the apache/nginx user to sudoers with NOPASSWD in order to work (Not very recommendable)